# Injecting JS into HTML pages with matching filenames

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, node-modules, gulp-inject

I want to be able to inject a `.js` file into the HTML page with the same filename using `gulp-inject` (i.e., `index.min.js` is injected into `index.html`, `data.min.js` is injected into `data.html`). I have the minified files stored in `build/js` and the `.html` is in `src/`. I've tried this:

```js
src('src/*.html')
    .pipe(inject(src('build/js/*.min.js'), {
        starttag: '<!-- inject:{{path}} -->',
        relative: true
    }))
    .pipe(dest('build/'));

await Promise.resolve('Javascript injected.');
```

Here's the terminal output when running it with `gulp`:

```
[23:17:24] Starting 'injectJS'...
[23:17:24] Finished 'injectJS' after 19 ms
[23:17:24] gulp-inject Nothing to inject into data.html.
[23:17:25] gulp-inject Nothing to inject into index.html.
```

`index.html` file with associated start and end tags:

```html
<!-- inject:index.min.js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

Can this be achieved using `gulp-inject` by itself, or will I need other packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. The issue was that by using `relative: true` in the options, the file path included `../build/js/` in front of the actual file name, which was solved by using `ignorePath: '../build/js'` to remove the extra path info. In the end, the `inject` call looked like this:

```js
inject(src('build/js/*.min.js', { read: false }), {
    removeTags: true,
    starttag: '<!-- inject:{{path}} -->',
    relative: true,
    ignorePath: '../build/js',
    transform: (path) => {
        return '<script src="js/' + path + '"></script>';
    }
})
```